# Extract the initials of first name and last name as well as number to form an ID number

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying this in Excel VBA.

It keeps using the last first name and surname in the column for all user ids.
Also trying to write user ids in column F.

```
Sub User()

Columns("F").Insert Shift:=x1ToLeft 'Inserts a column in between F and E
[F1].Value = "User ID"

Dim Number As String
Dim initial_1 As String
Dim initial_2 As String
Dim cell As Range
Dim txt As String

Dim x As Integer
NumRows = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

Range("A2").Select

For x = 1 To NumRows

    For Each cell In Range("B2:B1001")
        txt = cell.Value
        initial_1 = Left(txt, 1)
    Next cell

    For Each cell In Range("C2:C1001")
        txt = cell.Value
        initial_2 = Left(txt, 1)
    Next cell

    For Each cell In Range("E2:E1001")
        txt = cell.Value
        Number = Left(txt, 4)
        cell.Range("B1") = initial_1 & initial_2 & Number
    Next cell

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loops aren't right. Your code:

```
For x = 1 To NumRows

For Each cell In Range("B2:B1001")
txt = cell.Value
initial_1 = Left(txt, 1)
Next cell

For Each cell In Range("C2:C1001")
txt = cell.Value
initial_2 = Left(txt, 1)
Next cell

For Each cell In Range("E2:E1001")
txt = cell.Value
Number = Left(txt, 4)
cell.Range("B1") = initial_1 & initial_2 & Number
Next cell

Next
```

Lets think through an iteration.

Iteration 1:

1. `x=1` since that's the start of the first loop.
2. We now loop through every cell in `B2:B1001`
   **2a.** We are now inside this loop in the `B` column and we set `initial_1` to the first character in cell `B2`.
    
   **2b.** We just iterated to the next cell in that range so `B3`. We set `initial_1` to the first letter in `B3`. 
   **2c.** We just iterated to the next cell in that range so `B4`. We set `initial_1` to the first letter in `B4`. 
   ...
   **2LAST.** We finally made it to cell `B1001` and we set `initial_1` to the first letter in `B1001`. Note that `initial_1` hasn't been used yet, just set 1000 times over and over again. It will now retain the value set in this last iteration of this one loop we are in.
3. After all that looping we are now going to do the same loop through Column `C`. 
   **3a.** We are now inside this loop in the `C` column and we set `initial_2` to the first character in cell `C2`. 
   ...
   **3LAST.** We finally made it to `C1001` and we store the first letter of cell `C1001` to `Initial_2`.  Note that `initial_2` hasn't been used yet, just set 1000 times over and over again. It will now retain the value set in this last iteration of this one loop we are in.
4. Now do the same loop through Column E (you get the idea)
   **4a.** We now write `initial_1 & initial_2 & Number` to `B1`
   **4b.** We now write `initial_1 & initial_2 & Number` to `B1` (note the values in those variables didn't change because we already did those loops before we hit `4`)
   ...
   **4LAST.** We now write `initial_1 & initial_2 & Number` to `B1`
5. NOW we iterate to `X=2` and do ALL of this over again... which is the same steps we just took which means we do a lot of work for nothing.

Instead, loop once and do all of this logic in the 1 loop.

```
Sub User()

Columns("F").Insert Shift:=x1ToLeft 'Inserts a column in between F and E
[F1].Value = "User ID"

Dim Number As String
Dim initial_1 As String
Dim initial_2 As String    
Dim txt As String

Dim x As Integer
NumRows = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count



For x = 2 To NumRows
    initial_1 = Left(Range("B" & x).value, 1)
    initial_2 = Left(Range("C" & x).value, 1)
    Number = Left(Range("E" & x).value, 4)
    txt = Range("E" & x).value 

    'Now write this somewhere (surely not B1 over and over again) I'm guessing column F
    Range("F" & x).value = initial_1 & initial_2 & Number
Next


End Sub
```

Here's the same logic, but without having to sling so many variables around:

```
Sub User()    
    Columns("F").Insert Shift:=x1ToLeft 'Inserts a column in between F and E
    [F1].Value = "User ID"      

    Dim x As Integer
    NumRows = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    For x = 2 To NumRows
        Range("F" & x).value =  Left(Range("B" & x).value, 1) & Left(Range("C" & x).value, 1) & Left(Range("E" & x).value, 4)           
    Next
End Sub
```